# Resolve service by short class name while using RegisterAssemblyTypes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I would like to fetch component by short class name.
Example:

```
public interface ITransactionDef{}
public class Transaction1 : ITransactionDef {}
```

I will have hundreds of transaction classes. So I used this to register all ITransactionDef-s:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MyType).Assembly)
    .AssignableTo<ITransactionDef>().As<ITransactionDef>()
    .AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

However in my controller I have this:

```
public IActionResult GetTransaction([FromQuery]GetTransactionRequestDto actionRequestDto) 
{
    ITransactionDef trx = (ITransactionDef)serviceProvider
        .GetServices(typeof(ITransactionDef))
        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.GetType().Name == actionRequestDto.TransactionId);
    ...
}
```

I don't want this since it will construct all transactions on every request. I thought about three solutions:

1. Receive full class name in `actionRequestDto.TransactionId`, get type and use that type instead of `typeof(ITransactionDef)`. I would like to skip this. It seems a bit strange to have full class name somewhere in front end.
2. Use named component, however I didn't find a way to register component by its short class name. Also, I need to do this inside `RegisterAssemblyTypes`.
3. Using `TransactionDefRepository` and register components with it:

```
builder.Register(c => new TransactionDefRepository());

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MyType).Assembly).AssignableTo<ITransactionDef>().
            OnActivating(e => {
                TransactionDefRepository repository =
                    e.Context.Resolve<TransactionDefRepository>();
                ITransactionDef transactionDef = ((ITransactionDef)e.Instance);
                repository.Register(transactionDef);
            })
            .AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

And then use it in controller method:

```
Type trxType = trxRepository.GetTransactionType(actionRequestDto.TransactionId);
ITransactionDef trx = (ITransactionDef)serviceProvider.GetServices(trxType)
```

This won't work since OnActivating is called when component is asked for, so TransactionDefRepository is empty.

How can I implement this? Preferably without solution 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "short class name" I assume what you mean is `Type.Name` (`SomeTransaction`) rather than `Type.FullName` (`MyNamespace.SomeTransaction`).

You won't see anything specific to Autofac to help you here because types do need to be qualified. If you think about it, you might have `FirstNamespace.SomeType` and `SecondNamespace.SomeType` so the `Type.Name` is going to be the same thing. (Actually, you can technically have the same `Type.FullName` in *two different assemblies loaded at the same time* so you get into `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` at that point, but let's not get in the weeds there.)

Thus, if you want to solve it, likely you'll have to write something on your own.

However, there's one way I can you *could* do it using just Autofac, but it won't be available from an `IServiceProvider`, you'd have to use Autofac: **metadata**

When you register types, you can register with metadata. Add a `SimpleName` metadata value at registration time.

```cs
builder
  .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MyType).Assembly)
  .AssignableTo<ITransactionDef>()
  .WithMetadata("SimpleName", t => t.Name)
  .As<ITransactionDef>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Note I switched it to register them as `ITransactionDef` this comes in handy because you can inject the types into your controller *without resolving them* by using [the `Lazy<T>` relationship](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#delayed-instantiation-lazy-b), and you can query metadata using [the `Meta<T>` relationship](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#metadata-interrogation-meta-b-meta-b-x). They're combinable, so:

```cs
public class MyController
{
  private readonly IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<ITransactionDef>>> _transactionDefs;

  public MyController(IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<ITransactionDef>>> transactionDefs)
  {
    this._transactionDefs = transactionDefs;
  }

  public string SomeAction(RequestObject request)
  {
    var simpleName = request.GetTheSimpleName();

    // Find the right Meta<T> from the list
    var meta = this._transactionDefs.First(m => m.Metadata["SimpleName"].Equals(simpleName));
    // Get the Lazy<T> out of the Meta<T>
    var lazy = meta.Value;
    // Get the T out of the Lazy<T>
    var transactionDef = lazy.Value;

    // Now you have the right thing resolved
    transactionDef.DoWork(request);
  }
}
```

You can tighten that up into a one-liner LINQ query but I broke it down so you can see what's going on.

Anyway, that's one way to do it. You could technically wrap that in a factory if you wanted and then inject the factory.

```cs
public class DefFactory
{
  private readonly IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<ITransactionDef>>> _transactionDefs;

  public DefFactory(IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<ITransactionDef>>> transactionDefs)
  {
    this._transactionDefs = transactionDefs;
  }

  public ITransactionDef GetDef(string simpleName)
  {
    return this._transactionDefs
      .First(m => m.Metadata["SimpleName"].Equals(simpleName))
      .Value
      .Value;
  }
}
```

You can expand on the concept however you want. But, anyway, this is probably the easiest thing to do to get what you want.